# ping not working in a chroot

Tags: linux, security, chroot

How can I use the ping command in a chroot environment?

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
```

Currently I am using CentOs, but ideally there must be a solution that works in all chrooted environments.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: i get:  "ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Linux, `ping` needs to run as root (because it needs to bind a raw IP socket; ordinary users can only do UDP and TCP). It's designed to be setuid root. It looks like your copy in the chroot isn't setuid root. Fix the permissions:

```
chown root:root /bin/ping; chmod u+srwx,go=rx /bin/ping
```

Note that there may be other commands in the chroot that need to be setuid (or setgid), in particular `su` and `sudo`.

Note that this answers assumes a chroot, not something with more restrictions like a jail.

Comment: Or as an octal, `chmod 4755 /bin/ping`.

Answer (score 3):

As have been pointed out, `ping` needs the permission to bind a raw IP socket. Traditionally `setuid` has been used to allow normal users to use it.  However, using capabilities (POSIX 1003.1e, capabilities(7)), a minimal set of capabilities can be selectively enabled, limiting the security consequences of potential vulnerabilities.

`ping` needs the capability `CAP_NET_RAW`. Suppose that the path to the binary is `/usr/bin/ping`, the capability can be set using the tool `setcap`:

```
setcap cap_net_raw+ep /usr/bin/ping
```

Use `getcap` to check the result:

```
getcap /usr/bin/ping
```

The output should be something like

> /usr/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep

and `ping` should work now.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Thank you for helping me!

Comment: this does not work in a chroot environment as the user will not have the root permission.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem using ping or any other part of the gnu tool chain within a chroot,  so long as these binaries are present in your path.  If these commands cannot be accessed,  perhaps you should check your environment variables.